# How to move a table-game's pieces with drag and drop using python's tkinter and canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

As a beginner I would like to finish this project of a table game called "Ming Mang". I  created a GUI with python tkinter-canvas and can't seem to handle part where I get to move the pieces (that can only move in a + direction, no x movements) on the table. Please, note that I am a beginner in python, and don't really understand some of the advanced properties. So, it would be perfect if you could suggest a few simple functions (not too simple though :D ).

I will join my code bellow (if I can).

thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hgfw.png)

Comment: For things on your canvas to be drawn in real time, I think you need something like pygame.

Comment: please don't include your code as an image. It makes it impossible for us to cut and paste it.

Comment: Hey guys, I'm sorry to have had to upload the code in an image. for some reason, my code couldn't be well formatted in the post. :/